# Let Ax = b for a 3 by 3 matrix A where all the entries are nonzero , and Ax=b for some b iff b is in span ((1,1,1,),(1,0,1)). Find such a matrix A.

Tags: linear-algebra

This was a question on my exam and I have a feeling I did it wrong so I want to check :

Let $Ax = b$ for a 3 by 3 matrix $A$ where all the entries are nonzero , and $Ax=b$ for some $b$ iff $b$ is in span ((1,1,1,),(1,0,1)). Find such a matrix $A$.

Comment: So what did you write in the exam?

Comment: I think it should be "for some $x$" rather than "for some $b$". Also the link between the first half and the second half of that sentence is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a matrix $A$ such that $Ax=b$ has a solution for $x$ iff $b$ is in the mentioned span (call this subspace $S$), you must arrange that the columns of $A$ span that same subspace $S$, because by definition $Ax$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$ with coefficients taken from the entries of $x$. The easiest would be to take the mentioned vectors as the columns of $A$. But if they require you to take $A$ with $3$ (rather than $2$) columns, and no nonzero entries, then you must play around a bit find three vectors in $S$ without zero entries, and such that they span all of$~S$. Certainly $(1,1,1)$ could be the first of these vectors; now try to find one that is independent of the first to take as second column. For the third column you could just repeat the first or the second column, or you could go find another nice vector in$~S$ as third column. There are a lot of possibilities.

Comment: Yes that is what I am asking